# mypy 0.6.4 return type Optional[str] but sometimes you have prior knowledge about the type you will get

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I have a function that is returning either an `class instance` or `None` depending
on some logic.
In some places of the code I know this function is for sure not returning `None`,
but mypy complains.

I made a minimal example that reproduces the situation described above.

I would like to avoid marking `a_string` as `a_string: Optional[str] = ""`, I
know I can also overcome the problem using `cast` or `type ignore`, but somehow I
feel there might be a better way.

Any recommendations how to handle this situation?

For this example I am using `mypy 0.641` and `python 3.7`

```
"""
Function returns either an object or none

"""

from typing import Optional, cast

RET_NONE = False


def minimal_example() -> Optional[str]:
    if RET_NONE:
        return None
    else:
        return "my string"


a_string = ""
maybe_string = minimal_example()
a_string = maybe_string

# mypy doesn't complain if I do the following
a_string = cast(str, maybe_string)
a_string = maybe_string  # type: ignore
```

Mypy complains as follows:

```
❯❯❯   mypy mypy_none_or_object.py                                                                                                                                                                         (chatsalot)  ✘ 1
mypy_none_or_object.py:19: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[str]", variable has type "str")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mypy is designed to treat function signatures as the "source of truth". If you indicate that some function returns an `Optional[str]`, then mypy will assume that will always be the case. It won't attempt to see how any global variables may or may not alter that function signature.

The easiest possible way of working around this is to add an `assert` or `isinstance` check:

```
maybe_string = minimal_example()
reveal_type(maybe_string)           # Revealed type is Optional[str]
assert maybe_string is not None     # Or use 'if isinstance(maybe_string, str)
reveal_type(maybe_string)           # Revealed type is str
```

(If you're not aware, mypy will special-case the `reveal_type(...)` function: whenever mypy encounters it, mypy prints out the type of whatever expression you provide. This is useful for debugging, but you should remember to delete the pseudo-function after you're done since it doesn't exist at runtime.)

Alternatively, you could redesign your code so that your function's return value is more normalized -- it always returns a string instead of sometimes returning one.

If `RET_NONE` is meant to be a more-or-less immutable global (e.g. something like "enable debug mode" or "assume we're running on Windows"), you could use is to take advantage of mypy's `--always-true` and `--always-false` flags and provide two different definitions of `minimal_example`. For example:

```
RET_NONE = False

if RET_NONE:
    def minimal_example() -> None:
        return None
else:
    def minimal_example() -> str:
        return str
```

You then invoke mypy using `mypy --always-true RET_NONE` or `mypy --always-false RET_NONE` to match how your variable is defined. You can find more info about these types [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#platform-configuration) and maybe [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#version-and-platform-checks).

A fourth alternative you could explore is using function overloads: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#function-overloading

However, idk if that really works in your case: you can't define overloads where only the return type differs: the argument arity or types of each overload need to be distinguishable from each other in some way.

Comment: I included `RET_NONE` only as an example to express that the return type of that function changes at runtime and that one could know the return type before calling that function. I hope it didn't make my example confusing.

Answer (score 6):

Both solutions: `cast()` and `# type: ignore` are effectively turning off mypy checks for the variable. This can shadow bugs and should be avoided when possible.

In your case mypy cannot know the value of `RET_NONE`, since it can be changed in runtime from `False` to anything else, thus the error.

I suggest adding an assertion:

```
a_string = ""
maybe_string = minimal_example()
assert maybe_string is not None   # <- here
a_string = maybe_string
```

Now mypy is sure that on the next line `maybe_string` definitely won't be `None`. I covered this in the [**Constraining types**](https://blog.daftcode.pl/next-steps-with-python-type-system-efc4df5251c9) section of my blog post about typing.